Laravel10 Inertia failed test if make get in foreach
I have a problem with a Test with Inertia and Laravel 10.
In my test I have:
foreach ($users as $user){
   $this->actAsUser($user);
   $response = $this->get('myroute');
   $response  ->assertInertia(fn (Assert $page) => $page->component("Component"));
}

In this way I receive this error:

Not a valid Inertia response.

But If I try without use a ForEach for test all users and I try user by user, it works.
Example:
$this->actingAs($myUser);
$response = $this->get('myroute');
$response  ->assertInertia(fn (Assert $page) => $page->component("Component"));

$this->actingAs($myUser2);
$response = $this->get('myroute');
$response  ->assertInertia(fn (Assert $page) => $page->component("Component"));

I have

Laravel Framework 10.48.4
inertia-laravel 0.6.11

Does someone else has this problem?

Don't even worry about the issue, do not do more than 1 get call, on a test, use a DataProvider to do multiple tests reusing the test

Oh, thankyou, I didn't know DataProvider.
